# The concept of "opinion-based" questions needs serious revision. Otherwise SE is destined to mediocrity

Tags: discussion, policy

There are tons of topics on Meta about opinion-based questions. Obviously, the subject matter of opinion based questions is anything but intuitive.

---

Stack Exchange is about quality. Fine. Noted.

Stack Exchange is not about nonsense, off-topic discussions based on just shared opinions. Fine. Noted.

Stack Exchange's policy about opinion-based questions is unproductive. Not fine. At all.

---

This is just a personal opinion, sure. Do you want some sort of proof, though? Well, the above mentioned volume of questions about opinion-based questions. Plus, the dismally low volume of quality participation on Stack Exchange. Take the *[User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site for example. Probably the best discussion place for this matter in the English-speaking world. I personally know smart, reasonable and valuable experts in the field who are not choosing to share their experience on SE. This must be a red flag for those who care.

And finally, consider that this mere attempt for proof is an opinion, too. But it is not a mere opinion like that of stating that Stack Exchange's policy is unproductive. Nevertheless, it is still an opinion. But then, maybe it is not a primarily opinion-based answer. Did you get confused already?

---

By the way, if you take a glance over medicalsciences.stackexchange.com, it should be shut down ASAP, as it is infested with "opinion-based" questions. But no one is doing that? Why? I guess, the reason is because people involved in medical sciences know how little hard science there's in the broad field of biology. It is mostly "science in progress", inherently full of hypotheses, speculations, data open to various interpretations, decisions-based on personal observations, etc, etc, things which inevitably boil down to sharing opinions.

---

Things are actually simple.

When it comes to exact sciences such as mathematics, physics or chemistry, you can back your statements with proven facts.

When it comes to asking about documented facts such as "Which year did the Fukushima nuclear accident happen?", you can back your statements with sources about that fact. But those are easy to Google anyway and SE is not about a Q&A interface for Google searches, is it?

When it comes to asking about previous research, academic sources, etc., you can back your statements with specific information. This type of questions probably reflect the most valuable use of SE.

When it comes to sciences and disciplines which are far from the developed state of exact sciences, e.g. social sciences, biological sciences, humanities, every answer is more or less opinion-based. This is where SE's policy on opinion-based questions begins to contradict itself and wreak havoc and frustration.

SE's policy **should distinguish** between opinions substantiated by personal experience and reasoning, and opinions not substantiated by anything such as "I have been in this field for 30+ years and I am telling you" or simply "I think that..." But the former should be allowed, "institutionalized" by proper definitions and regulations and probably, visually labelled as "evidence-based opinion questions" or something like that.

---

In conclusion, I dare say, Stackexchange leaders are religious about preventing the problem of opinions in answers, but it is the wrong problem on the first place. The problem are not opinions, the problem are unsubstantiated opinions.

Comment: There are definitely sites out there that work mostly on answers written from experience and you might want to read this blog.post about how they fit into the model of SE: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: @gnat - mine is not a question (but it's funny, how the use of the SE platform for Meta brings users to think in terms of questions alone. Btw, here's a suggestion on the topic: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386656/the-stack-exchange-platform-is-not-a-good-fit-for-meta-activities).

Comment: You're using the Question entry on Stack Exchange, and you find it funny people interpret your ..commentary as a question? Also: please give actual proof if you want to illustrate a point, instead of referring to proof. How is "the above mentioned volume [which is where exactly?] of questions about opinion-based questions" proof of SE's policy about opinion-based questions? Who are those "smart, reasonable and valuable experts in the field who are not choosing to share their experience on SE" you speak of? What are the reasons they gave for not sharing their experiences?

Comment: Moreover: you signed up for this site, having been able to know its stance on (their definition of) opinion-based Q&A. You don't have to be here. Things are actually *that* simple.

Comment: and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48899/282094

Answer (score 9):

> Tons of topics on Meta about opinion-based questions. Obviously the subject matter of opinion based questions is anything but intuitive.

Meta is for talking *about* the main sites. While we still value objectivity and fact-based discussions on meta, there is room for opinions and feelings too (in moderation). See [What is Meta Stack Exchange, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47634/997587) and /help/whats-meta

> Stack Exchange's policy about opinion-based questions is unproductive.

... says who?

> Well, the above mentioned volume of questions about opinion-based questions

links or it's not real.

> Plus, the dismally low volume of quality participation on Stack Exchange

We are what we are. If there's less traffic, we're not going to dramatically change what we are to lure people in. Go share some post links to external sites or something :P

> I personally know smart, reasonable and valuable experts in the field who are not choosing to share their experience on SE. This must be a red flag for those who care.

Have you asked them why? What does this have to do with opinions? If they have expertise that they could contribute, it is very much welcome here!

> And finally, consider that this mere attempt for proof is an opinion, too.

If you really want to attempt to prove anything, show us data. Go write some SEDE queries (https://data.stackexchange.com/).

> When it comes to sciences and disciplines which are far from the developed state of exact sciences, e.g. social sciences, biological sciences, humanities, every answer is more or less opinion-based. This is where SE's policy on opinion-based questions begins to contradict itself and wreak havoc and frustration.

Really now?

- @"*far from developed*": See all the sites with "research" in their name and description.
- @the rest of that paragraph, see the rest of [the site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites). I'm too lazy to cherry-pick right now.

> SE's policy should distinguish between opinions substantiated by personal experience and reasoning, and opinions not substantiated by anything

We do...

As you've already been linked to in the comments, see https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/. We do allow certain kinds of subjective questions- questions that:

- inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
- tend to have long, not short, answers
- have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
- invite sharing experiences over opinions
- insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
- are more than just mindless social fun

That blog post is linked in every network site's `/help/dont-ask` (What types of questions should I avoid asking?) page.

Comment: Obviously, the ailment is in terminal phase... This is what happens when engineer-mindset guys build a social platform. Not accusing this type of people at all. The blame is to all people from social sciences backgrounds, who, as a whole, have really not built anything valuable on the web. I have no hopes for SE improving, but it can and it should serve as a stepping stone for a next great knowledge sharing platform.

Comment: Well, you see, that's the thing. **Stack Exchange is not a social platform and was not built to serve as one**. You're judging an elephant by its ability to climb trees, so to speak. As for "The blame is to all people from social sciences backgrounds", I have no idea what those people have to do with your opinion of Stack Overflow...

Comment: @F1Krazy - any platform involving interaction between humans is a social platform. Anyway, it's hopeless.

Comment: @drabsv no, it's not. Social platform is something that is **meant to be social** in the first place, and focused on social aspects. Not just anything where humans visit site and can interact with each other.

Comment: @drabsv - Agree ... SE is ***NOT*** a social platform. While there is some social interaction, given we have chat rooms and to an extent Meta sites, the purpose of SE is for knowledge exchange. That's the whole reason opinions should be minimized in the first place. Obviously opinions and socializations creep in, but that should be the exception and not the rule.

Comment: @drabsv uh, do you have any counter-argument(s), or you just throwing accusation now?

Comment: @justANewbie - what accusations? I mentioned only one, single accusation and it does not even refer to the people behind SE development.